# Given $p^2+q^2+r^2+1=s+\sqrt{p+q+r-s}$, solve for $s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The real numbers $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$ satisfy 
>   $$p^2+q^2+r^2+1=s+\sqrt{p+q+r-s}$$ 
>   Find the value of $s$.

I don't even know how to start. Thanks!

Comment: This is a single variable equation except the constants are written as $p,q,r$ etc. Would it be easier if the question stated $$a=s+\sqrt{b-s}$$instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t = \sqrt{p+q+r-s}$, the equation is equivalent to
$$\begin{align} & p^2+q^2+r^2+1 = (p+q+r-t^2) + t\\
\iff & \left(p - \frac12\right)^2+\left(q - \frac12\right)^2+\left(r - \frac12\right)^2 + \left(t - \frac12\right)^2 = 0\\
\implies & p = q = r = t = \frac12\\
\implies & s = p + q + r - t^2 = \frac54\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Square both sides. To avoid tedium in writing you may make the substitutions $m=p^2+q^2+r^2+1,\,n=p+q+r.$

Comment: I am not sure this is different from the comment by Peter Foreman.

Comment: @NoChance I'm not sure why you can't see the difference.