# The real numbers $a,b,c,d$ satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2+1=d+\sqrt{a+b+c-d}$. Find the value of $d$.

Tags: radicals, algebraic-equations

The real numbers $a,b,c,d$ satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2+1=d+\sqrt{a+b+c-d}$. Find the value of $d$.

I've been given this question for a class I'm taking and I'm not really sure where to start. I let $\sqrt{a+b+c-d}=x$ and tried to find a factorization but haven't really gotten anywhere with it. Hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, it seems this problem is causing headache for a lot of your classmates. this is the third time I see this question recently. In any event, look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3355615/given-p2q2r21-s-sqrtpqr-s-solve-for-s/3355797#3355797)

Comment: Are you sure that you have made no typo?

Comment: Is $d=\frac{5}{4}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Solve the equation 
$$d^2-2d(a^2+b^2+c^2+1)+d+(a^2+b^2+c^2+1)^2-(a+b+c)=0$$ for $d$